# Loop through nested JSON arrays and order items by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I'm trying to order my JSON array by value. In the sample below, the first item is `"503": "07:25"`. The `07:25` is what I would like the rows to be ordered by alphanumerically.

```
    "333": [

        {
        "503": "07:25",
        "507": "06:00",
        "500x": "06:50",
        "500x": "07:20",
        "500": "07:35",
        "503": "07:50",
        "507": "07:40",
        "500x": "07:55",
        "500": "08:30",
        "500x": "08:00",
        "500": "10:45",
        "507": "09:05",
        "500": "10:45",
        "507": "09:05",
        "500": "13:45",
        "500": "16:45",
        "500": "20:00",
        "500": "22:00",
        "500N\n*Thur/Fri Only": "23:00"
        },
        {
        "500": "12:00",
        "500": "17:00",
        "500": "21:30",
        "500N": "00:45"
        },

        {
        "500": "18:45"
        }

        ],

"334": [{
        "503": "07:26",
        "507": "06:01",
        "500x": "06:51",
        "500x": "07:21",
        "500": "07:36",
        "503": "07:51",
        "507": "07:41",
        "500x": "07:56",
        "500": "08:31",
        "500x": "08:01",
        "500": "10:46",
        "507": "09:06",
        "500": "13:46",
        "500": "16:46",
        "500": "20:01",
        "500": "22:01",
        "500N\n*Thur/Fri Only": "23:01"
        },
        {
        "500": "12:01",
        "500": "17:01",
        "500": "21:31",
        "500N": "00:46"
        },
        {
        "500": "18:46"
        }

        ],
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is ordering each of the arrays by value so that it looks like this

```
"333": [

    {
    "507": "06:00",
    "500x": "07:20",
    "503": "07:25",
    "500x": "06:50",
    ...
```

Is there anyway that I can loop through the entire file and output an array ordered by value. I've been trying to achieve this in javascript but with no luck.

Comment: Ordering can be done using javascript once you load it. How are you reading the Json file with javascript?

Comment: In your desired output, the values are going in ascending order until the last value (06:50), is that on purpose?

Comment: @mygeea I am just storing it all in a single variable and using a for loop to go through array item. Inside this for loop is another for loop to go through the 3 nested arrays like in the sample

Comment: @RobM. It might appear that some of them are in ascending order but they are actually randomly entered. The full json file has them in a random order.

Comment: i was asking about your desired output, not the initial data

Comment: Sorry I misread. The desired output should be that they are in descending order. A solution to this is no longer needed as it appears the JSON is invalid as multiple keys are not unique.

Comment: If you don't need a solution (because you have no valid JSON), please delete this question.